# Display an ASCII table of characters 32 to 112 with bash

Tags: bash, shell

Please, I want to know how to display an ASCII table of characters 32 to 112.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following command

```
man ascii
```

It shows ascii table.

For displaying ascii from 32 to 112

```
for((i=32;i<=112;i++)) do printf "$i --> ";printf \\$(printf '%03o\t' "$i");printf '\n' ;done;printf "\n"
```

Comment: What I want to do 
Display an ASCII table of characters 32 to 112.

Output format expected:

N columns (variable)
Each column contains:
ASCII decimal code with 0 inital, displayed in bold.

Comment: @ahlamberhil: you need to add these requirements to your question - people here are not mind-readers.

Comment: Thank you, and if I want to display the value in hex

Comment: for((i=32;i<=112;i++)) do printf "%x -->" "$i";printf \\$(printf '%03o\t' "$i");printf '\n' ;done;printf "\n"

Comment: tnahks you, i need the hexadecimal value

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite succinctly with `Perl` like this:

```
perl -E 'say $_," --> ",chr($_) for (32..112)'
```

**Sample Output**

```
32 -->  
33 --> !
34 --> "
35 --> #
36 --> $
37 --> %
38 --> &
39 --> '
40 --> (
41 --> )
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> jot -s '' -c - 32 112
> ```

—  or —

> ```
> jot -s '' -c 80 32
> ```

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnop
```