# A bash loop to echo all possible ASCII characters

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

I know how to print all letters

> {a..z} and {A..Z} and {0..9}

But is there a way to print all possible ASCII Characters via a bash loop?

Comment: Define "*all possible ASCII Characters*". 0-127 or extended ASCII 0-255? What about the non-printable characters?

Comment: Try `man ascii`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48905712/2836621

Comment: I meant regular ASCII (0-127)

Answer (score 3):

If it is okay to use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=32;i<127;i++) printf("%c", i)}'
```

Or using `printf`:

```
for((i=32;i<127;i++)) do printf "\x$(printf %x $i)"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop

```
echo -e \\x{0..7}{{0..9},{A..F}}
```

It prints all chars from 0 to 127.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
for ((i=32;i<127;i++)) do printf "\\$(printf %03o "$i")"; done;printf "\n"
```